# KVM image format convertion: raw thin provisioning to raw preallocated

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, disk-image

I'd like to convert a *KVM virtual machine disk image* in raw file from a **thin privisioning** format to **preallocated**.

In the first place I've got a preallocated 20Gb raw image file:

```
image: /var/lib/libvirt/images/ArchLinux.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 20G (21474836480 bytes)
disk size: 20G
```

I used the following command to make the backup disk file:

```
sudo qemu-img -O qcow2 -cp ArchLinux.img BackupArchlinux.qcow2
```

After that I tried to get the first image file back using:

```
sudo qemu-img -O raw -p BackupArchlinux.qcow2 Archlinux.img
```

but I get a thin privisioned raw format as you can see here:

```
image: .../ArchLinux.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 20G (21474836480 bytes)
disk size: 1.6G
```

How can I convert this raw file to preallocated format back?

**Note**: *qemu-img version 2.11.0*

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your edition, I learned something 'bout markdown ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fully preallocate a RAW image, rather than copying/converting the whole image with `qemu-img`, you can simply issue `fallocate <image_file> -l <size_to_preallocate>`

In your case, you can issue `fallocate ArchLinux.img -l 20G`.

Of course, do a backup *before* messing with the disk's image file.

Comment: Perfect! I did: `fallocate NewArchLinux.img -l 20G` and now `qemu-img info NewArchLinux.img
image: NewArchLinux.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 20G (21474836480 bytes)
disk size: 20G`